# D3.js - How to map continuous domains to discrete ranges with scales?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to make a scale thats relates a continuous domain with a discrete range. My attempt is this one:

```
var scale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, 15.43])
    .range([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]);
```

So the domain will be from 0 to 15.43 taking all possible float numbers. How can I tell the scale to take all numbers from 0 to 15.43?

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for [`scale.quantize`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales#quantize-scales):

```
var q = d3.scale.quantize().domain([0, 1]).range(['a', 'b', 'c']);

console.log(q(0));
console.log(q(0.3));
console.log(q(0.35  ));
console.log(q(0.5 ));
console.log(q(1));
```

Of course, the range values can also be numeric.